# Sell products by weight (kgs) in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, checkout, sales-order

I want to create **a custom module in magento** from where we can **select product to be ordered based on weight (kgs.)** not units.

For e.g If I want to sell apples, we will sell based on kgs. not units.

Comment: i assume  that you sort  productd at category and search page by weight.?

Comment: And what exactly is the difference between kgs and units? Please describe your problem some more. FYI: Magento accepts decimals in qtys through configuration (see the Inventory tab on the product edit page).